# C++ classes and pointers (Me again with my Tile classes :D)

Tags: c++, class

Link to my last topic:
[C++ class forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9119236/1023753)

Now main thing:

I decided to change all returned types to pointers to avoid memory leaks, but now I got:

```
27 C:\Dev-Cpp\Projektyyy\strategy\Tiles.h ISO C++ forbids declaration of `tile' with no type 
27 C:\Dev-Cpp\Projektyyy\strategy\Tiles.h expected `;' before "tick"
```

Its only in base class, everything else is ok... Every function in tile class which return *tile has this error...

Some code:

```
class tile
{
      public:
          double health;
          tile_type type;
          *tile takeDamage(int ammount) {return this;};
          *tile onDestroy() {return this;};
          *tile onUse() {return this;};
          *tile tick() {return this};
          virtual void onCreate() {};
};
```

Comment: You don't "avoid memory leaks" by "changing all returned types to pointers". You avoid them by writing correct code.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I need to have pointers to have correct code :)

Comment: @kittyPL: That's debatable and impossible to tell from your code. Modern C++ usually contains hardly any naked pointers or `new` expressions at all, and `delete` never, so I wouldn't bank on it that you're up to a good solution...

Comment: @kittyPL : You certainly do not!

Comment: @gamernb when I read your comment I thought "pff, im not so stupid...", but then looked in my code and BANG! :D Double facepalm for me, would be a vote up and accept for you :)

Comment: @kittyPL I highly doubt that, but even if that is true, you using pointers will most likely lead [to more memory leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-is-it-a-memory-leak-what-could-i-catch-if-i-shall-use-such-things-in-c/8840302#8840302), not avoid them.

Comment: @ildjarn if you mean that I have inline functions, you are right, but it's only a base class (Im going to make it virtual) and subclasses have separate files for headers and definitions :)

Comment: @kittyPL : No, I mean that you certainly do not need to have pointers to have correct code. (And _most_ memory leaks are caused by _using_ pointers, not by not using them...)

Comment: @ildjarn Well, read the topic in link and try to think a better way to change class...

Comment: @kittyPL : Armen's answer (which _you_ selected as the correct answer) already shows you the way to change the class -- notice that he doesn't use any pointers!

Comment: @ildjarn sorry, I dont understand. I have 2 separate classes in his answer. Im going to have tile foo[X][Y] tab, and I have tile children classes. I want to change tile_tree into tile_tree_apple (when apples grow up)... How to do that? I decided to use return value to assign new object to my map tab. Do you know any better way?

Comment: @ildjarn well, answer please, Im not sure about my decision. Still can change everything... :D

Comment: @kittyPL : I don't understand your last question at all, so I can't answer it, sorry. I'm only arguing against use of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon on the return for `tick`, and the `*` goes after the type when declaring pointers:

```
tile* tick() {return this;};
```

Comment: Also put the * after tile, like so:

    tile * name;

Answer (score 2):

```
class tile
{
      public:
          double health;
          tile* takeDamage(int ammount) {return this;}
          tile* onDestroy() {return this;}
          tile* onUse() {return this;}
          tile* tick() {return this;}
          virtual void onCreate() {}
};
```

Here you go. I removed tile_type since I don't know what that is. Probably an enum. Apart from that you had lots of issues with semi-colons.