# C++ connect many headers to one and use those headers functions

Tags: c++, header

guys, I have a question, I don't know how can I connect many headers in one header, let's call it "Master header" and use functions from that headers, for example

```
// A.h
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A();
  void showMessage(string msg);
};

// B.h
class B {
public:
  B();
  void CountMessages()
};

// C.h
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

class C : public B, public A {
public:
  C();
  void DoSomething();
}
```

and I want to call function CountMessages from class 'b' using a class an object of class 'c' and/or a class 'a', like

```
//c.cpp
#include "C.h"
#include "B.h"    
#include "A.h"

extern A b_obj;
extern B a_obj;

C::DoSomething() {
  b_obj.CountMessages();
  a_obj.showMessage("Hello");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ class forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119236/c-class-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question, I don't know how can I connect many headers in one header, let's call it "Master header" and use functions from that headers,

Create the file and add `#include` lines for all the other header files.

MasterHeader.h:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
```

c.cpp:

```
#include "MasterHeader.h"
```

**Caution:** I wouldn't recommend this practice in general. This is useful only if the interface provided by `"MasterHeader.h"` is primary, with `"A.h"`,`"B.h"`, and`"C.h"` serving the purpose of ease of maintenance.

Comment: well, "C.h" is that "MasterHeader.h", so I should just include it into any cpp file and call all that functions, that I need ?