# Initialize a class on top level that's defined bottom level in the same header file

Tags: c++, class, c++11, namespaces

Might be a dumb question. My apologies, but I would like to do the below,

```
connectionState currentState;

class connectionState {
    public:
        .......
        .......
};
```

rather

```
class connectionState {
    public:
        .......
        .......
};

connectionState currentState;
```

The former doesn't compiles at all while the latter does. So, no way to do this?

Comment: You can do that with pointers and forward declaration. But, with objects, it needs the full class definition prior to instantiating.

Comment: No way. What problem do you have that you think this will solve?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I know my example is not enough to display what it actually solves. But I believe in my case, It's good for my eyes at least because I can see all globally declared ones on top of file rather at random places.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks for introducing me into forward declaration.  Found a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119236/c-class-forward-declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are forward declarations for this. Forward declarations also resolve the problem of circular dependencies:

```
class connectionState; // forward class declaration
extern connectionState currentState; // forward global extern variable declaration, now possible because connectionState is declared as a typename/class name
static connectionState currentState; // forward global static variable declaration 

class connectionState { ... }; // implementation/definition, can access currentState
connectionState currentState = ...; // definition/initialization
connectionState currentState {...}; // definition/initialization
```

Comment: You would need `extern connectionState currentState;` to make it a forward declaration (currently this is a definition and does not compile)

Comment: Not to forget: `static` and `inline`, etc... variables