# C++ Enum inside a class - order of declaration matters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010, and can't quite get, how is this class wrong (syntax error : identifier 'EnumType ') and won't compile:

```
class BrokenClassWithEnum
{
private:
    void useEnum (EnumType enumType); //syntax error : identifier 'EnumType '
public:
    enum EnumType 
    {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3
    };
}
```

And this is OK:

```
class WorkingClassWithEnum
{
public:
    enum EnumType 
    {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3
    };
private:
    void useEnum (EnumType enumType);
}
```

What happened to the class scope?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with scope -- you have to declare what `EnumType` is before you use it. That's just how C++ is.

Comment: The `enum` here is a red herring, any kind of type would do, including `typedef int EnumType;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ any referenced non-built-in name must have been declared somewhere earlier.

It might appear that this rule has an exception for class definitions, because the following works fine:

```
struct S
{
    void foo() { cout << x_ << endl; }
    int x_;
    S(): x_( 42 ) {}
};
```

However, the rule about declaration-before-use applies to the transformed code

```
struct S
{
    inline void foo();
    int x_;
    inline S();
};

void S::foo() { cout << x_ << endl; }
S::S() : x_( 42 ) {}
```

which is what the compiler "proper" sees. And here there is no use of anything that hasn't already been declared.

The proper C++03 solution to your problem is to define the enumeration type before its first use. With C++11 you can alternatively forward-declare it, but then an underlying type must be specified,

> **C++11 §7.2/3**:
>   “An *opaque-enum-declaration* is either a redeclaration of an enumeration in the current scope or a declaration
>   of a new enumeration. [*Note:* An enumeration declared by an *opaque-enum-declaration* has fixed underlying
>   type and is a complete type. The list of enumerators can be provided in a later redeclaration with an *enum-
>   specifier*. *—end note* ] A scoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as unscoped or with a different
>   underlying type. An unscoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as scoped and each redeclaration
>   shall include an *enum-base* specifying the same underlying type as in the original declaration.”

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the order of definition (not declaration) matters but a forward declaration will resolve this error - at least in MSVC++ 6.  Outside of MSVC++ 6 you should specify a storage type to forward declare an enum (the requirement for specifying the storage type in a forward enum was in the C++0x standard)

NOTE: VC++ 6 will allow the storage type to be omitted, but if you are forward declaring an enum, you should declare the storage type (SEE BELOW):

#### This will resolve the error in VC++6.  However, VC++6 does not appear to support a STORAGE TYPE for an enum inside a class as required by the C++0x standard:

```
class BrokenClassWithEnum {
public:
    enum EnumType;

private:
    void useEnum (EnumType enumType); 
public:
    enum EnumType {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3
    };
};
```

---

#### Normally I.E. within a C++0x compliant compiler you would use something like:

```
class BrokenClassWithEnum {
public:
    enum EnumType : int;

private:
    void useEnum (EnumType enumType);
public:
    enum EnumType : int {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3
    };
};
```

**NOTE:**Forward declaration of enums is possible in some but not all C++ versions:

[Forward declaring an enum in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: "I don't think the order of definition (not declaration) matters" it does. "a forward declaration will resolve this error" non-standard without a storage class (and C++03 didn't have that). however, it can work as a microsoft visual c++ specific solution.

Comment: Why even mention MSVC 6.0 anyway? That's dead and gone.

Answer (score 3):

Within the class definition itself, items must appear in order (with dependent items appearing before the items that depend on them) like they do at any other scope. Inside a class method *body* (even if inlined) the entire definition of the class is available.

Answer (score -1):

I believe member variables can be accessed before declarations within the class because class validation or compilation is done in two pass.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).