# Is it possible to separate enum values from declaration?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a .h file :

```
class MyClass
{
  enum MyTypes{
     type1 = 1,
     type2 = 2,
     type3 = 3,
     // and so on
  };
};
```

Is it possible to separate the " = value " from this declaration to another location, namely the related cpp file? The reason is that this enumeration has weird values provided by a remote server that I do not control. I would like to remove it from client's eyes.

I'd like to have a .cpp file with

```
enum MyClass::MyTypes{
  type1 = 12,
  type2 = 14,
  type3 = 28,
  // and so on
};
```

But the compiler says that I redefine MyTypes, which is true.

Comment: why put it in .cpp file will resolve the issue from remote server?

Answer (score 4):

To corroborate [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448932/is-it-possible-to-separate-enum-values-from-declaration#comment32366292_21448974)'s comment, C++11 allows you to forward declare enums. The following code will fail in C++03 but compile in C++11:

```
struct S {
    enum E : int;  
};

enum S::E : int {
    a,b,c
};
```

[N2764](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2764.pdf) as well as [Forward declaring an enum in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c) go into more detail, but:

> The reason the enum can't be forward declared is that without knowing
>   the values, the compiler can't know the storage required for the enum
>   variable.

This is not necessary for an `enum class` because the default type is int.

---

A "workaround" is to forward declare a struct containing an enum. Credit goes to [Leszek Swirski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11382046/1508519). Note: variadic macros are a gcc extension in C++03.

```
#define ENUM_CLASS(NAME, TYPE, VALUES...) \
struct NAME { \
  enum e { VALUES }; \
  explicit NAME(TYPE v) : val(v) {} \
  NAME(e v) : val(v) {} \
  operator e() const { return e(val); } \
  private:\
  TYPE val; \
}

struct Enum;

void f(Enum e);

ENUM_CLASS(Enum, int,
 VALUE,
 ANOTHER_VALUE
);

void f (Enum e)
{
 switch(e)
 {
  case Enum::VALUE:
    std::cout << "VALUE" << std::endl;
    return;
  case Enum::ANOTHER_VALUE:
    std::cout << "ANOTHER_VALUE" << std::endl;
    return;
 }
}

f(Enum::ANOTHER_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However I cannot use C++11 due to platform restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible using `enum`. I can think of several possible solutions:

1. Use global static variables. This means you only need to declare the variables in the .h file and you can define and initialize them in a .cpp file.
2. Create a class with getter methods that return the values.
3. Create a single getter method that returns the "real" values based on a "dummy" enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward declare the `enum`:

```
class MyClass
{
    enum MyTypes;
};
```

followed by

```
enum MyClass::MyTypes
{
    type1 = 12, // ...
};
```

No one but your class will be able to use these names because they are not yet defined; given that the `enum` is `private` in the example anyway, that should be fine.

Comment: Not sure about inside classes, but outside of classes, you'd need to specify the underlying type. Edit: Yeah, try removing the underlying type from [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98b3676b2f16ed1f).

Comment: @chris Some rationale might be found in this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/72599/1508519). It seems you already know about that though, given from your example.

Comment: But then the users including the h file containing MyClass won't know about the enumeration. It defeats what I try to accomplish here

Comment: @remyabel, Come to think of it, I think I learnt it from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations) of all things. I have to say the list of changes there is (or was when I was looking for something like that) pretty useful.