# Invalid type declaration for enum

Tags: c, gcc, enums, wrapper, typedef

In a `C` wrapper for a library (`C++`) I have the following code:

```
#ifndef _CWRAPPER_H__
#define _CWRAPPER_H__

// representation of a class inside the library:
typedef struct Foo Foo;  /* This compiles both with gcc and VS */

// representation of an enum inside the library:
typedef enum Bar Bar; /* gcc: "invalid type in declaration", VS compiles fine */

#endif  // _CWRAPPER_H__
```

Why is this declaration illegal in gcc but not in VS? How can I fix it?

I'm using VS 2010 and in a virtual machine Eclipse CDT with gcc 4.8.1.

EDIT: Apparently it has to be compiled as `C++` to reproduce this error.

---

One workaround could be to declare it as:

```
typedef unsigned int Bar;
```

which does the trick if one provides all valid numbers `Bar` can take.

Comment: I do not have any problem with `typedef enum Bar Bar;` and gcc. You have probably another Bar defined before this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I haven't. Anyway the error message does not point to a redundant definition..

Comment: The code you present compiles fine, so it's impossible to diagnose the problem with it. Please show code that exhibits the problem you describe ([SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/))

Comment: This reproduces for me with g++ 4.8.2. I also get the error: "error: use of enum 'Bar' without previous declaration" before the error mentioned in the question. Note that the code has to be compiled as C++ - there's no error when compiled as C.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : try with `-pedantic` for C.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: yes, I get a warning with `-pedantic` when compiled as C: "warning: ISO C forbids forward references to 'enum' types"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `typedef` needs a valid type. In the case of `typedef struct Foo Foo`, it doubles as a forward declaration of `struct Foo`, which satisfies the needs for the `typedef`. In the case of `typedef enum Bar Bar`, this doesn't work, since `enum`s can't be forward declared.

Ref. eg. ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §6.7 :

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;98)
>
> — for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
>   identifier.

C++ has a similar constraint : [Forward declaring an enum in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c).

It seems VS 2010 allows this as an extension.

Comment: What could be a suitable way to avoid multiple declarations then?

Comment: @fiscblog : you can't have multiple declarations for an `enum` (see the quote I added to my answer). The one declaration is also the definition. Generally, you'd put that in a header file, and include it everywhere the `enum` is used.