# Why not C++ (not C++0x) support enum forward declaration?

Tags: c++

I use enum type but declare it under the use, compile fail.

Then I add a forward declaration, but still compile fail.

I search exists questions about enum forward declaration, found c++ (not C++0x) does not support enum forward declaration.

Can somebody explains why ?

I found similar questions on SO, but nobody explains why.

Comment: The answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c) explain why.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).