# How to resolve `no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'std::map<AudioTypes, const char *>`?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I followed this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296298/1983337) for my purposes, and I really do not know how to resolve this error. When I try to access `audioType[wav]` or `audioType[mp3]`, the error below comes up. Looking up the internet was not helpful for me.

`error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const std::map<AudioTypes, const char *>`

`note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::map<AudioTypes, const char *>', but method is not marked const
    mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& __k);`

```
// WAVFile.h
class WAVFile {
    // ...
    private:
        enum AudioTypes: int;
        static std::map<AudioTypes, const char*> audioType;
    // ...
}

// WAVFile.cpp
enum AudioTypes: int {
    wav,
    mp3
};

static map<AudioTypes, const char*> audioType = {
    {wav, "wav"},
    {mp3, "mp3"}
};

bool WAVFile::exportAudio(const char* filename, const char* filetype) {
    // temporary test code    
    cout << audioType[wav] << endl;
    return true;
}

// main.cpp
int main() {
    file.exportAudio("export_i ran.wav","wav") ? cout << "Exported\n" : cout << "Failed\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call a non-const method on a const object. std::map's [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is not const (afaik because it can/must create an entry if the object for that key doesnt exist).

Comment: How is this code called?  The error message looks pretty self explanatory.  You are trying to call a non const function on a const object.

Comment: [Please post the code that actually reproduces the issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bb397ef1a1c7c5c)

Comment: @NathanOliver These lines are inside a class `WAVFile`, and they are called from an external .cpp file housing `main()`

Comment: That doesn't help.  Seeing the code would help.

Comment: @NathanOliver edited!

Comment: When defining audioType, you should prefix it with the class:   `static map<AudioTypes, const char*> WAVFile::audioType = {`
Otherwise you're declaring another variable with the same name ! Same remark for the enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already pointed out, the reason for that error is - as the error message explains - that `operator[]` of `std::map` is not a `const` qualified member function. (I'm a bit surprised by this, I thought there was a `const` overload)

A possible fix is to use the [member function `at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), which has this const qualified overload, and should thus be working with `const` qualified `std::map`s.

Also note that in the code you showed there's a possible issue:

```
class WAVFile {
        static std::map<AudioTypes, const char*> audioType;
}
```

and

```
static map<AudioTypes, const char*> audioType = {
    {wav, "wav"},
    {mp3, "mp3"}
};
```

are not the same variable. You should add the class scope before the definition and get rid of the `static`:

```
map<AudioTypes, const char*> WAVFile::audioType = {
    {wav, "wav"},
    {mp3, "mp3"}
};
```

Moreover, you should either move the definition of `enum AudioTypes` to the header, or possible provide a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280969/1116364).

Answer (score 1):

After fixing a few issues, in particular the missing `WAVFile::` before `audioType` and `AudioTypes` and the static before the definition of `audioType`, this code builds:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class WAVFile {
    public:
        bool exportAudio(const char* filename, const char* filetype);

    private:
        enum AudioTypes: int;
        static std::map<AudioTypes, const char*> audioType;
};

enum WAVFile::AudioTypes: int {
    wav,
    mp3
};

map<WAVFile::AudioTypes, const char*> WAVFile::audioType = {
    {wav, "wav"},
    {mp3, "mp3"}
};

bool WAVFile::exportAudio(const char* filename, const char* filetype) {
    cout << audioType[wav] << endl;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    WAVFile file;

    file.exportAudio("export_i ran.wav","wav") ? cout << "Exported\n" : cout << "Failed\n";

    return 0;
}
```