# extern enum in header file

Tags: c++, enums

In my project, I have a header file containing the following lines.

```
extern enum class options {alpha, beta, gamma, theta};
extern options P1, P2;
```

Compilation gives me

> error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and
> functions

Why?
How can I rectify this?

Compiler: GCC 9.2.0

Comment: `extern` means the thing I am applied to is defined somewhere else.  How would you apply that to a definition?

Comment: Regarding your edit of *I wish to spilt it up into a declaration in the .h file and a definition in a .cpp*.  I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280969/4342498) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632184/4342498) have your answer.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` is applied to variables to specify that they have external linkage.  What you have is not a variable but an `enum` definition, therefore `extern` cannot be applied to it.

What you can do is apply `extern` to variables at file scope of the `enum` type.

For example, your header file would have:

```
enum options {alpha, beta, gamma, theta};

extern options myoption;
```

And in **one** source file you would have:

```
options myoption;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Spillting up produces more errors.

Comment: Do you mean - `enum options {alpha, beta, gamma, theta};` goes into the.cpp file and `extern options myoption;` goes into the .h file?

Comment: @PalLaden Both go in the header file, then in **one** .cpp file add `option myoptions;` for the definition.

Comment: Please put your comment in the answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no storage associated with an enum class definition.  So it doesn't make sense for it to be marked as extern.

A variable whose type is an enum class, on the other hand, can certainly be `extern` because there's storage associated with a variable to hold the value of that variable.  The location of this storage is something that the linker must ultimately work out.

It makes sense to know of the existence of a variable without being responsible for designating storage for it at link time. This is how you get global variables. For example:

**main.cpp**

```
int foo = 5; // declaration and definition together.
```

**other.cpp**

```
extern int foo; // declaration only, (external definition still required elsewhere)
// but you can now use `foo` in this file. e.g.:
int examineFoo() {
  return foo;
}
```

This is also useful if you want to provide a declaration of a global variable in a header file.  For example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
int foo = 5;
```

**foo.h**

```
extern int foo;
```

**other.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
int examineFoo() {
  return foo;
}
```

It's okay to encounter both the extern declaration and the definition in the same file.  e.g.:

```
extern int foo;
int foo = 5;
```

#### To fix your problem

To fix exactly the example you provided, you can remove `extern` from the enum class definition, where it does not make sense to have it.

```
enum class options {alpha, beta, gamma, theta};
extern options P1, P2;
```

Remember that some non-extern definition of those variables `P1` and `P2` will be required in another module in order for your program to link if you make use of them.

For you, you probably want the class to be defined in a header, along with an extern declaration of any global variables (yuck) you want in your program.

**options.h**

```
enum class options {alpha, beta, gamma, theta};
extern options P1, P2;
```

**options.cpp**

```
#include "options.h"
options P1 = options::alpha, P2 = options::beta;
```

In options.cpp you include options.h to get the definition of the enum class. It also came with an extern definition of the global variables `P1` and `P2`, which wasn't strictly necessary as they are going to be defined in this file anyway, but it's not illegal to do it.

**other.cpp**

```
#include "options.h"
options examineOptionP1() {
   return P1;
}
```

other.cpp is aware of the class definition for `options` **and** is aware of extern declarations of P1 and P2.