# How do you forward declare a imported TLH namespace so that you can use it in a structure definition?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, namespaces, circular-dependency

If I declare this `struct` in my `CDialog` header:

```
struct S_MWB_AUTO_ASSIGN_SETTING
{
    bool bIncludeReferencedWeeks{};
    bool bAvoidConflicts{};
    MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType eAssignType;
    CString strStartingName;
    void (CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::* pfnSetAssignName)(CString);
};
```

Then, I can use it in the dialog functions. Example:

```
std::vector<S_MWB_AUTO_ASSIGN_SETTING> vecAutoAssignSettings =
{
    {true, true, MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_Host, L"Name 1", &CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::SetVideoHost },
    {true, true, MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType_CoHost, L"Name 2", &CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::SetVideoCohost },
};
```

This compiles and builds fine. Now, I tried to move my `struct` definition into another header file. Snippet:

```
namespace CChristianLifeMinistryDefines
{
    struct S_MWB_AUTO_ASSIGN_SETTING
    {
        bool bIncludeReferencedWeeks{};
        bool bAvoidConflicts{};
        MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType eAssignType;
        CString strStartingName;
        void (CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::* pfnSetAssignName)(CString);
    };

}
```

Now it will not compile:

> error C2653: 'MSAToolsLibrary': is not a class or namespace name
>
> error C3646: 'eAssignType': unknown override specifier
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

The `MSAToolsLibrary` namespace is created automatically by a TLH file. The problem is that the wrapper class that uses the TLH file also references the same header I am trying to add the `struct` too:

```
#pragma once
#include "ChristianLifeMinistryDefines.h"

#include <map>
#include <vector>

#ifdef _WIN64
#import "..\\..\\MSAToolsLibrary\\MSAToolsLibrary\\bin\\x64\\Release\\MSAToolsLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only named_guids
#else
#import "..\\..\\MSAToolsLibrary\\MSAToolsLibrary\\bin\\x86\\Release\\MSAToolsLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only named_guids
#endif

using namespace CChristianLifeMinistryDefines;
```

I tried to `#include` the TLH wrapper header. No joy.

At the moment I have kept the `struct` in the `CDialog` header.

I understand about forward declaring structures etc. This feels like a circular reference issue but I cant establish how to forward declare the namespace that is built by the TLH import.

Comment: The structure must be defined after the `#import` directive that introduces `MSAToolsLibrary`. E.g. by putting both in the same header, one after the other; or setting up a header that does `#import` first, and includes the header with the structure's definition second.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, I tried moving the `#include` of the `Christian...` header to after the import else / if and it still caused the compile error.

Comment: This means that somewhere you include the structure but not the `#import` directive.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But if I add the `#include msatools.h` to the top of the `christian` header, so that the import is done first, then the `msatools` header which includes the christian header after the import says that the christiahn namespace is not valid????

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If I add the import e;se / if in both headers, then it compiles.

Comment: You don't need to forward-declare a namespace. You need to forward-declare `AssignmentType` in that namespace. Which I'm guessing is an enum, and there's no mechanism in C++ to forward-declare untyped enums. If you can't arrange for the structure to be defined after `#import`, one possibility is to make `S_MWB_AUTO_ASSIGN_SETTING::eAssignType` a plain `int`, with the understanding that its values would come from `MSAToolsLibrary::AssignmentType`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, I understand. I like it staying as an `enum` because of intellisense. Thanks for the explanation. I will leave the structure define in the dialog header.

Comment: You can forward-declare a typed `enum` or a `enum class` if that is preferrable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c

Comment: @user17732522 It probably won't help. I'm pretty sure `#import` directive manufactures plain old untyped and unscoped enums.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Correct, they are untyped. It is why I have a barrage of code analysis warnings about those enaumes wherever I use them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, nevermind then. That's why I deleted my original comment anyway. I don't know about these MSVC-specific features. Sorry for the noise!