# Forward-declaration of enum member of template-specialization - fails with GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, enums, forward-declaration

I know that, generally, we [can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71416/1593077) forward-declare enums in C++11.

So, why does this:

```
enum kind_t { kind1, kind2 };

template <kind_t Kind> struct foo {};

template <> struct foo<kind1> {
    enum named : int;
};

enum foo<kind1>::named : int {
    named1 = 123,
    named2 = 456,
};
```

fail to compile with GCC (12.1)? The error [is](https://godbolt.org/z/cqx7jbaq9) (Godbolt):

```
<source>:9:6: error: cannot add an enumerator list to a template instantiation
    9 | enum foo<kind1>::named : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:9:6: error: cannot add an enumerator list to a template instantiation
    9 | enum foo<kind1>::named : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

This seems to [compile fine](https://godbolt.org/z/cqx7jbaq9) with clang++ 14.0...

Comment: It's interesting, that if you mark the definition with `template<>` it becomes invalid for clang, but valid for gcc - https://godbolt.org/z/GGjjcnPMx

Comment: @TheDreamsWind: That's right... my IDE was complaining about the template<>, but actually it seems like it should be there... or should it?

Comment: [temp.mem.enum](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem.enum) is the closest part of standard i've managed to find so far, but it has nothing about specialisation/instantiation restrictions

Comment: The above code compile with Visual Studio. However the fact that not compiler agree might indicate an area that is not yet well defined... and probably not very used.  Do you any reason of mixing template and forward declared enumerations?

Comment: See [CWG 1485 Out-of-class definition of member unscoped opaque enumeration](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1485).

Comment: @Phil1970: Yes. I declare the template in a more general header, along with other stuff in struct foo (it's basically a traits class) and define the enum values in separate headers that are related to the specific instantiation.

Comment: Then, why not put the template specialization in the same header where the enum is defined? Alternatively, why not defining top level `enum` and put have something like `enum kind1_named; template <> struct foo<kind1> { using named = kind1_named; };`

Comment: @Phil1970: Because the specialization has very few requirements, while all sorts of declarations depend on it.