# c++ forward declare enum of class

Tags: c++, enums, forward-declaration

Suppose I have the following enum inside class

```
class A
{
    enum E {a,b};
};
```

I know that since c++11 we can forward declare enum, because it's default type is int. But how can I forward declare enum E of class A in case class A is only declared and not defined?

And if it is not possible then why?

Comment: This cannot be done.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what is the reason?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280969/4117728 "As long as the size of the enumeration is specified by the application, it can be forward declared" you cannot forward declare your `E` even if it was outside of the class

Comment: *I know that since c++11 we can forward declare enum, because it's default type is int.*  That is not correct, you'd need to explicitly declare the backing store type: `enum E : int {a,b};`

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72599/4117728 for why not

Comment: It can be done `class A{ enum E: int; };` and then definition `enum A::E: int {};`

Comment: @user7860670 thats not a forward declaration of OPs `A::E`

Comment: It *is* a forward declaration of `A::E`.

Comment: @user7860670 whats the point? You define a different `A::E`. OPs `A::E` cannot be forward declared

Comment: @user7860670 But OP mentioned that he wanted this forward declaration to be done when A is also forward declared (not defined yet)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number There is only one `A::E`

Comment: @Fareanor Yes, is is not possible to forward declare any class members without defining class therefore it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @user7860670 what prevents the compiler from accepting? wherever I use this enum, the compiler will know what exact size to allocate for it.

Comment: Because C++ requires for `A` to be defined when accessing some member using `A::E` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that since c++11 we can forward declare enum, because it's default type is int.

Not quite. You can only forward declare an enum when the underlying type is explicitly specified. This is not allowed:

```
enum A;
enum A { X,Y};   // not allowed
```

With gcc the error message is still a little misleading, stating that it would be disallowed to forward declare enums in general which isn't correct anymore (https://godbolt.org/z/xYb5cKEWP).

This is ok

```
enum A : int;
enum A : int { X,Y};
```

Note that the default is not simply `int`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> [...] the underlying type is an implementation-defined integral type that can represent all enumerator values; this type is not larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0. If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Now try this when, as the question describes, the enum is an inner class member. "But how can I forward declare enum E of class A in case class A is only declared and not defined?"

Comment: @Sam the answer is no because you cannot forward declare `enum E {a,b}` whether inside a class or not. Though I agree that this answer fails to explain the case of `class A { enum E : int {a,b} };`. Just cannot fix it now